# Why query error (1267): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,IMPLICIT)

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Why i am getting error
query (1267): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<='

in this select operation:

```
set @dataFiltro="2021-12-31";
select * from LibroSociAnni 
where inizioAssoc<=@dataFiltro and termineAssoc>=@dataFiltro
```

while no error if I use:

```
set @dataFiltro=convert("2021-12-31" using utf8);
select * from LibroSociAnni 
where inizioAssoc<=@dataFiltro and termineAssoc>=@dataFiltro
```

Comment: because to know if two strings are equal or their order if not, they need to have the same collation, and specifying the character set gets a default collation for that character set.  when you don't specify the character set, I believe it is getting it from your connection.

Comment: Check the collation of the connection, the column, the database, and maybe something else.  Are any stored routines used?  What is the application language?